# Separability of languages in RE

Tags: computability

Say that a language $C$ is a *separator* for disjoint languages $A$ and $B$ if $A \subseteq C$ and $B \subseteq \bar{C}$.

I need to find two languages $A,B\in \mathrm{RE}$ that have no recursive separator $C$.

Comment: What did you try?  Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help with conceptual problems but we're not here to solve exercises for you.

Comment: Note: this is very similar to Sipser problem 4.20.

Comment: Hint: what if $A=C$ and $B=\overline{C}$?

Comment: We'll I have tried a few approaches, first you can notice that since $C \in R$ so is $\bar{C} \in R$.
I've tried to build a reduction using the fact that $A \cup B \in RE$ and build a TM that will be equivalent to H_{tm}, but that didn't work.
I'm not looking for a solution to copy, more of a hint towards a possible solution

Comment: Ran.G, in the case $A=C$ and $B=\bar{C}$, C is a recursive separator.

Comment: I have tried the following,
$A\equiv \left \{<M,w> | \ M \ halts \ on \ w \ and \ M \ has \ an \ even \ number \ of \ states  \right \}$
B is defined the same with the slight change of odd number of states.
clearly, $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, and $A \cup B = H_{tm}$.
Now, I'm trying to show that if $C \in R$ then also $A \cup B \in R$, I encountered some problems and then I thought my claim is probably false.
At the moment I'm trying a different approach of set theory and closure properties in order to find the contradiction.
Any suggestions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9843/are-co-semidecidable-languages-separated-by-decidable-ones  (is it even a dupe?)

Comment: Yes, I missed the requirement for $B$ be in RE as well. The hint works if $B$ is in coRE.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Such sets $A,B$ (sans the requirement of recursive enumerability) are called *recursively inseparable*. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursively_inseparable_sets) "it is possible for $A$ and $B$ to be recursively inseparable, disjoint, and recursively enumerable", and Wikipedia might have relevant examples.  (Even if not, now you know what term to look for in the vast sea of internet.)

Extra hint: Wikipedia does indeed provide two such examples:

1. $A$ is the set of encodings of TMs whose output is $0$, $B$ is the set of encodings of TMs whose output is $1$.
2. $A$ is the set of provable tautologies, $B$ is the set of refutable contradictions.

Comment: that's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: A complete answer is a faux pas, since it's probably a homework exercise.

Answer (score 0):

So, this is what I came up with:

$A=\left\{ \left \langle M \right \rangle \ | \ \left \langle M \right \rangle \in\  L(M)\right\}$

$B=\left\{ \left \langle M \right \rangle \ | \ \left \langle M \right \rangle \notin\  L(M)\right\}$

Now, let's assume there exists such a $C \in R$ s.t. $B \subseteq C$ and $A \subseteq \overline{C}$

Let $M_C$ be a TM such that $L(M_C)=C$.

Now, consider $M_C(\left \langle M_C \right \rangle)$

If $M_C$ accepts, then $\left \langle M_C \right \rangle \in A$ by A's definition. Because $A \subseteq \overline{C}$, we get that $\left \langle M_C \right \rangle \notin C$ so $M_C$ rejects.

On the other hand, if $M_C$ rejects, then $\left \langle M_C \right \rangle \in B$ so we get $\left \langle M_C \right \rangle \in B \subseteq C$ so we get that $\left \langle M_C \right \rangle \in C$, so $M_C$ accepts.

Contradiction.

Comment: Is $B$ recursively enumerable?

Comment: Nope, you're right, $B \in Co-RE$, I guess this isn't a valid proof.